# Tomcat 8 - static resources / assets can't get this working

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

C:\asset (there I have images like 1.jpg / 2.jpg / 3.jpg etc)

My tomcat server.xml looks like this:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="/test" docBase="C:/asset" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="false"/>

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

Still when i go to localhost:8080/test/1.jpg I have 404 error any ideas why this don't work ?

Another question is there any possibility to configure this path in my spring project ? As a variable ?

Comment: I think you still need a folder c:\asset\web-inf with a web.xml

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the log files?